# How can I copy spreadsheet cells into word document?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel, microsoft-word

I'm trying to copy a selection of cells within a spreadsheet across the word and have changes appear in both sp doc and Wd doc.  I have read this answer you gave from another with the same quest:

> Open both the Word document and the Excel worksheet that contains the
>   data that you want to create a linked object or embedded object from.
>   Switch to Excel, and then select the entire worksheet, a range of
>   cells, or the chart that you want. Press CTRL+C. Switch to the Word
>   document, and then click where you want the information to appear. On
>   the Home tab, in the Clipboard group, click the arrow under Paste, and
>   then click Paste Special. In the As list, select Microsoft Office
>   Excel object. Click Paste to insert an embedded object, or click Paste
>   link to insert a link to the object.

Those are the instructions from Microsoft. So... did you use the Paste Special... and then selecting the Microsoft Office Excel Object option?

Highlight, copy, paste special, Mic Off EX Object and then Paste link. 
Selection appears in WORD DOC - Identical -great.
The problem arises in WORD.  If I change a figure in Excel, as I understand it, it should also change in WORD. MINE DOESN'T!!!!!! Aaaahhhhhh!  Have repeated the exercise so many times.

I have the version of Office that came with Windows 7... And yes, I saved each pasting in both documents.

Hi CharlieB.  Thanx.  But I have just accidentally solved my problem.  In WORD, Instead of Ctrl S, I right clicked and found UPDATE LINK, and it did Tada!!! Thanx anyway.

Comment: could you specify the version of Office? Sounds like 2003 to me, i cannot replicate your issue in 2010, it just works there. Did you save the Excel file (it works for me without saving it, so this is just a thought)

Comment: I am also not able to duplicate your issue with Office 2010. What happens when you save the Word document? Does it update then? Have you checked the security settings? Is the Excel sheet on a network location which Word might not trust for a connection?